# What's wrong with my org-mode capture settings?

Tags: org-mode

I've been trying to setting the capture configuration for org-mode, however, when I try to select a capture template, I get this message:

```
Template key: 
byte-code: Capture template `p': listp
```

Here is my conf:

```
       (setf org-footnote-auto-adjust t
             org-directory (expand-file-name "~/org")
             org-archive-location (concat org-directory "/archivado.org::* Entradas viejas y archivadas")
             ;; ...
             org-agenda-files (list (concat org-directory "/trabajo.org")
                                    (concat org-directory "/notas.org")
                                    (concat org-directory "/otros.org")
                                    (concat org-directory "/agenda.org"))
             org-log-done 'time
             org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "/notas.org")
             org-capture-templates '(("p" "Cosas por hacer" entry (file+headline (concat org-directory "/otros.org") "Tareas")
                                      "* Tareas %?\n  %i\n  %a")
                                     ("d" "Diario" entry (file+datatree (concat org-directory "/diario.org"))
                                      "* %?\nInsertado el %U\n  %i\n  %a")
                                     ("a" "Apuntes importantes" entry (file+datatree "")
                                      "* Notas importantes %?\nNota importante del %U\n  %i\n  %a")
                                     ("g" "Agenda" entry (file+datatree+prompt (concat org-directory "/agenda.org"))
                                      "* Agenda %?\n Ingresado el %T\nProgramado para el %:date\n  %i\n"))
             org-clock-persist 'history)

       ;; ...
       (define-key global-map (kbd "C-c c") 'org-capture)
       (org-clock-persistence-insinuate)
```

If I press <kbd>a</kbd> I get this error:

```
Template key: 
org-capture-set-target-location: Invalid capture target specification
```

But according to the manual this `(file+datatree "")` should be valid, what I'm missing?

Comment: Could you provide a shorter working example? Most of these configs are unrelated, and some quick testing should be enough to tell you which parts are relevant.

Comment: I though one could just copy and paste unto \*scratch\* buffer, evaluate the buffer and try to reproduce the issue, and I included the entire org-mode conf because I though it was convenient than not including something that may be causing this problem!

Comment: What version of org are you using? I don't see file+datatree in it. I see file+datetree.

Comment: `Org-mode version 8.2.8 (8.2.8-elpa @ /home/jorge/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20141006/)`. I corrected that misspell in my conf, thanks! I still get the `Capture template `p': listp` thing and with "Agenda" and "Diario" I get `org-capture-set-target-location: Invalid capture target specification`though...

Comment: @JorgeArayaNavarro yes, we can paste and eval the whole thing. And the next thing we'll do is gradually remove parts of it until the bug disappears. :-) I'm just saying you'll get help faster if you do the second part yourself (gradually reduce the config, until you find which part causes the problem, and post that part). Of course, that's goes not just for this site, but anywhere on the internet people will always ask you for a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after following the advices posted here, and doing some debugging, I found out that my issue was caused by the line `(setf org-blank-before-new-entry t)`, commenting it enabled me to capture annotations.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that the valid specification is `file+datetree` and you have `file+datatree`.

This is true for your `Diario`,`Apuntes importantes` and `Agenda`.  If you correct that one spelling mistake it will allow them to resolve properly.

Tested this with `emacs -q`, adding current org to the load path, requiring it then evaluating the `setf`.  It no longer gave errors (other than directory not already existing since I use `~/documents/org` instead of `~/org`.

Comment: really? because I make the corrections, saved the file, closed emacs, opened it again, pressed <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and I still get those annoying `byte-code: Capture template `g': listp`. This is without removing anything from my org-mode configuration. Tomorrow I'll try again just letting the `org-capture-templates` defined in my conf.

My org-mode version is `Org-mode version 8.2.8 (8.2.8-elpa @ /home/jorge/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20141006/)` what's yours?

Comment: My Lord and my God, it works if I comment almost everything in my org-mode conf except what I said I wouldn't comment. I did a quick test, commenting everything again and uncommenting it line per line until I hit the issue. The problem is with `org-blank-before-new-entry t` in my configuration, I don't know exactly why, but commenting it and uncommenting the rest don't make this issue happens again. btw, which answer should I mark as correct? Should I better answer myself?

Answer (score 3):

You've got this:

```
'(("p" "Cosas por hacer" entry (file+headline (concat org-directory "/otros.org") "Tareas") ...
```

but the `concat` part won't get evaluated: a string is expected after `file+headline`, and you've provided a list, hence the error. Try the following instead: (note the backquote)

```
`(("p" "Cosas por hacer" entry (file+headline ,(concat org-directory "/otros.org") "Tareas") ...
```

To see the difference in result, you can play about evaluating those two expressions by placing the cursor after them and using `C-x C-e`.

P.S. Prefer `expand-file-name` to `concat` when joining directory and filenames to make a path.

Comment: Actually, I think there's a second problem. This throws an error upon saving the template, he is getting (the `listp p` thing) an error upon first invoking the capture (I tested his config and the error does indeed happen).

Comment: Yup. these changes didn't solved the issue!

Comment: Back quoting isn't needed in this case, he's using `setf` rather than `setq`.

Comment: @Jonathan That won't make a difference. If you pass a `quote` to `setf`, it's not suddenly going to start looking inside it and evaluating parts of it. If the set data is to contain the result of the `concat`, which was my assumption, then the above is correct. If `org-agenda` itself actually evaluates the `(concat ...)` form, then this will of course be unnecessary.

Comment: Oops, missed that logic.  However there is something odd.  In past incarnations I know I had had to backquote-expand certain elements in org-capture templates and org-agenda templates to get them to work properly, but with his example they properly expanded to `~/org/otros.org` when attempting the capture.

Comment: Presumably `org-agenda` is evaluating it now then. In any case, my answer didn't help much. :-)